# How do i add or import pyqt and sip to Python

Tags: user-interface, qt4, python-3.x, pyqt4

im having trouble importing this. i am a newbie so please use layman words i can follow:p. riverbank said i need sip. but there is a sip folder in the pyqt download i installed, so do i have it already? there are some related questions on this site, which lead me to try these method:.. my pyqt folder is PyQt-win-gpl-4.9.4. so i typed:
sys.path.append('C:\Program Files\PyQt-win-gpl-4.9.4\sip') this adds it fine, inside the 'sip' folder, it has a bunch of folders like QtCore etc.. and ive tried importing like this:

```
from sip import QtCore
```

ImportError: No module named sip

or

```
import sip
```

ImportError: No module named sip

Can someone please tell me what im doing wrong? should i have just installed PyQt in the original Python folder? i really want to be able to type the code while trying to learn it as its getting very confusing. thanks

Comment: from PyQt4 import QtCore
ImportError: No module named PyQt4

Answer (score 2):

The folder name `PyQt-win-gpl-4.9.4` belongs to the *source* package.

For Windows, what you need is the *binary* package. The binary package contains everything you need for PyQt development (including Qt itself). The only requirement is that you have Python installed first.

Go back to the [riverbank download page](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download), scroll down a bit, and you will find a list of installers for various versions of Python. Download the one that is appropriate for your system, and run it.

Once you've done that, fire up a Python interpreter and do:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
```

to make sure everything is working correctly.

If you need tutorials, the [PyQt Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) is not a bad place to start.

Comment: hey thanks for the help ekhumoro. i downloaded the file. the folder name is PyQtX+_py323_q482_pyqt494.pkg.mpkg and i extracted it to my Python directory. the import line isnt working. is there a specific folder in my Python directory i must put this folder in?

Comment: @LoloLolo. No. Don't extract anything. The file you need to download is an `exe` file installer (e.g. PyQt-Py3.2-x86-gpl-4.9.4-1.exe). There's a list of links at the bottom of the riverside download page. Just download the appropriate one, and double-click the file to run it. There is no need to copy folders into the python directory - the installer will do everything automatically.

Comment: thank you so much ekhumoro. i downloaded the exe and the import works. i had to download the 3.1 version as it says thats the version of Python i have. I will check out the PyQt wiki tutorial you provided. thanks again:)

Answer (score -1):

Copying sip.pyd from folder **PyQt5_sip-4.19.12-py3.7-win-amd64.egg** to **PyQt5-5.11.2-py3.7-win-amd64.egg** did the trick for me.....It does not seem to be right approach but at least you will not stuck in waiting for fixes to come...Please let me know if still do not work....