# How to make a beautiful neon effect in Qt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I want to make a beautiful and juicy neon effect with the ability to control the power of light. For this, I built such code

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(800, 800)

        self.setStyleSheet('background:black;')


        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        color_1 = '162, 162, 162,'
        color_2 = '255, 255, 255,'
        color_3 = '0, 255, 255,'

        d_ = 1

        power = int(255/100*d_)

        for x in range(6):
            label = QLabel(self)


            color_L = color_1
            glass_L = 255
            size_L = 60
            blut_L = 0


            label.raise_()

            if x < 1 :
                color_L = color_1
            elif x < 2 :
                color_L = color_3
                glass_L = power
            elif x < 3 :
                color_L = color_2
                blut_L = 6
                glass_L = power
            elif x < 4:
                color_L = color_2
                blut_L = 40
                glass_L = power
            elif x < 5 :
                label.lower()
                color_L = color_3
                blut_L = 40
                size_L = 70
                glass_L = power
            elif x < 6 :
                label.lower()
                color_L = color_3
                blut_L = 150
                size_L = 70
                glass_L = power

            label.setText('test')
            label.setStyleSheet('background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);color:rgba({} {}); font-size:{}px;'.format(color_L, glass_L,size_L))
            label.resize(self.width(), self.height())
            label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

            self.effect = QGraphicsBlurEffect(blurRadius=blut_L)
            label.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

but the code is too cumbersome. And the light turned out to be too unnaturalistic,

[image]

it looks especially bad if you indicate a weak light intensity.

Are there any better options to make a neon effect? or why does he look so bad?

Comment: The code could be slightly improved (but it's just about readability and usability, not a real performance gain): no need to do all those `if` statements, just create a function that returns all values in the correct order (so that you don't need to do `lower()` each time). Besides that, it looks "bad" because this is not what QGraphicsBlurEffect was created for, so you're just creating a "composition" that resembles what you want to achieve. I'm afraid that the only alternative is to create your own QGraphicsEffect subclass, possibly by the size of the effect and/or changing the blur color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I eventually decided it was fun to do it :-)

**IMPORTANT**: Consider that this is some sort of a hack, because it uses a *private* and undocumented function of Qt (which is the same used by QGraphicsBlurEffect) and it's not guaranteed it will work everywhere.
I've been able to achieve it by borrowing some code from a Live tv viewer known as [Atropine](https://github.com/russdill/atropine-tv), the interesting parts is in the [effects.py](https://github.com/russdill/atropine-tv/blob/master/effects.py) source.

Note that a similar effect can probably be achieved by using "abstract" drawing of a private QGraphicsScene within the QGraphicsEffect itself, but it would be much more slower (since you'll have to create new QGraphicsPixmapItems each time the `draw()` method of the effect is called) and would probably have some side effects.

The trick was to get the function name through ctypes, I've only been able to find the exported function names in Linux and Windows (but I wasn't able to test it there):

```
    # Linux:
    $ nm -D /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so |grep qt_blurImage
    004adc30 T _Z12qt_blurImageP8QPainterR6QImagedbbi
    004ae0e0 T _Z12qt_blurImageR6QImagedbi

    # Windows (through Mingw):
    > objdump -p /QtGui4.dll |grep blurImage
        [8695] ?qt_blurImage@@YAXAAVQImage@@N_NH@Z
        [8696] ?qt_blurImage@@YAXPAVQPainter@@AAVQImage@@N_N2H@Z
```

I cannot do testing for MacOs, but I *think* that it should be the same command line as it's on linux.

If you don't have GNU binutils on Windows, use the `dumpbin` utility.

Note that these names seem to be somehow consistent along the same operating system *and* Qt versions: I run the same `nn` command on the old `libQtGui.so` file for Qt4 and it gave the same result.

Yet, on Windows, the string has slightly changed since some version of Qt5 (I'm not sure which one, but probably after 5.8) and seems still valid in Qt6:

`?qt_blurImage@@YAXPEAVQPainter@@AEAVQImage@@N_N2H@Z`

---

So, here's your *beautiful neon effect*...

[image: a wonderful neon effect!]

And here's the code, I've added an example program to test it:

```py
import sip
import ctypes
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    # the exported function name has illegal characters on Windows, let's use
    # getattr to access it
    _qt_blurImage  = getattr(ctypes.CDLL('Qt5Widgets.dll'), 
        '?qt_blurImage@@YAXPAVQPainter@@AAVQImage@@N_N2H@Z')
else:
    try:
        qtgui = ctypes.CDLL('libQt5Widgets.so')
    except:
        qtgui = ctypes.CDLL('libQt5Widgets.so.5')
    _qt_blurImage = qtgui._Z12qt_blurImageP8QPainterR6QImagedbbi


class NeonEffect(QGraphicsColorizeEffect):
    _blurRadius = 5.
    _glow = 2

    def glow(self):
        return self._glow

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def setGlow(self, glow):
        if glow == self._glow:
            return
        self._glow = max(1, min(glow, 10))
        self.update()

    def blurRadius(self):
        return self._blurRadius

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    @pyqtSlot(float)
    def setBlurRadius(self, radius):
        if radius == self._blurRadius:
            return
        self._blurRadius = max(1., float(radius))
        self.update()

    def applyBlurEffect(self, blurImage, radius, quality, alphaOnly, transposed=0, qp=None):
        blurImage = ctypes.c_void_p(sip.unwrapinstance(blurImage))
        radius = ctypes.c_double(radius)
        quality = ctypes.c_bool(quality)
        alphaOnly = ctypes.c_bool(alphaOnly)
        transposed = ctypes.c_int(transposed)
        if qp:
            qp = ctypes.c_void_p(sip.unwrapinstance(qp))
        _qt_blurImage(qp, blurImage, radius, quality, alphaOnly, transposed)

    def draw(self, qp):
        pm, offset = self.sourcePixmap(Qt.LogicalCoordinates, self.PadToEffectiveBoundingRect)
        if pm.isNull():
            return

        # use a double sized image to increase the blur factor
        scaledSize = QSize(pm.width() * 2, pm.height() * 2)
        blurImage = QImage(scaledSize, QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
        blurImage.fill(0)
        blurPainter = QPainter(blurImage)
        blurPainter.drawPixmap(0, 0, pm.scaled(scaledSize, 
            Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        blurPainter.end()
        
        # apply the blurred effect on the image
        self.applyBlurEffect(blurImage, 1 * self._blurRadius, True, False)

        # start the painter that will use the previous image as alpha
        tmpPainter = QPainter(blurImage)
        # using SourceIn composition mode we use the existing alpha values
        # to paint over
        tmpPainter.setCompositionMode(tmpPainter.CompositionMode_SourceIn)
        color = QColor(self.color())
        color.setAlpha(color.alpha() * self.strength())
        # fill using the color
        tmpPainter.fillRect(pm.rect(), color)
        tmpPainter.end()
        
        # repeat the effect which will make it more "glowing"
        for g in range(self._glow):
            qp.drawImage(0, 0, blurImage.scaled(pm.size(), 
                Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))

        super().draw(qp)


class NeonTest(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QGridLayout(self)

        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(palette.Window, Qt.black)
        palette.setColor(palette.WindowText, Qt.white)
        self.setPalette(palette)

        
        self.label = QLabel('NEON EFFECT')
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.label.setPalette(QApplication.palette())
        self.label.setContentsMargins(20, 20, 20, 20)
        f = self.font()
        f.setPointSizeF(48)
        f.setBold(True)
        self.label.setFont(f)
        self.effect = NeonEffect(color=QColor(152, 255, 250))
        self.label.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)
        self.effect.setBlurRadius(40)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel('blur radius'))
        radiusSpin = QDoubleSpinBox(minimum=1, maximum=100, singleStep=5)
        layout.addWidget(radiusSpin, 1, 1)
        radiusSpin.setValue(self.effect.blurRadius())
        radiusSpin.valueChanged.connect(self.effect.setBlurRadius)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel('glow factor'))
        glowSpin = QSpinBox(minimum=1, maximum=10)
        layout.addWidget(glowSpin, 2, 1)
        glowSpin.setValue(self.effect.glow())
        glowSpin.valueChanged.connect(self.effect.setGlow)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel('color strength'))
        strengthSpin = QDoubleSpinBox(minimum=0, maximum=1, singleStep=.05)
        strengthSpin.setValue(1)
        layout.addWidget(strengthSpin, 3, 1)
        strengthSpin.valueChanged.connect(self.effect.setStrength)

        colorBtn = QPushButton('color')
        layout.addWidget(colorBtn, 4, 0)
        colorBtn.clicked.connect(self.setColor)

        self.aniBtn = QPushButton('play animation')
        layout.addWidget(self.aniBtn, 4, 1)
        self.aniBtn.setCheckable(True)

        self.glowAni = QVariantAnimation(duration=1000)
        self.glowAni.setStartValue(1)
        self.glowAni.setEndValue(10)
        self.glowAni.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.InQuad)
        self.glowAni.valueChanged.connect(glowSpin.setValue)
        self.glowAni.finished.connect(self.animationFinished)

        self.aniBtn.toggled.connect(self.glowAni.start)

    def animationFinished(self):
        if self.aniBtn.isChecked():
            self.glowAni.setDirection(not self.glowAni.direction())
            self.glowAni.start()

    def setColor(self):
        color = QColorDialog.getColor(self.effect.color(), self)
        if color.isValid():
            self.effect.setColor(color)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = NeonTest()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

<sup>Remember that this answer was provided for Qt5: since Qt6, PyQt (and, later, PySide) switched to actual Python types for flags and enums, so you shall use full namespaces for all of them (for instance, `Qt.GlobalColor.black`, etc.).</sup>

Note that, based on my tests, using a glow factor higher than 1 with a blur radius less than 4 might result in some painting artifacts.

Also, some care has to be taken with the palette. If you want, for example, apply the effect to a QLineEdit, you'll probably also want to set the `QPalette.Base` to transparent:

[image: a glowing line edit!]

I've been able to test it successfully on two Linux machines (with Qt 5.7 and 5.12), if anyone would care to comment about testing on other platforms I'll be glad to update this answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but what is "import sip"
I have set "pip install sip" and "pip install PyQt5-sip"
BUT paython does not find the SIP module

Comment: If you have PyQt, you should already have sip. Maybe check the installation of PyQt5 and search here on StackOverflow about similar errors.

Comment: The only thing I found was a question on [PYQT4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285782/how-do-i-add-or-import-pyqt-and-sip-to-python) , but there, as I understand it, they recommend installing sip separately. And this question will not help me. In the folder PyQt5 there is a `sip.cp37-win_amd64.pyd file.` Is this file responsible for sip?

Comment: Now the code throws an error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\neon.py", line 35, in <module>
    _qt_blurImage  = getattr(ctypes.CDLL('QtGui5.dll'),
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module was not found`

Comment: Maybe it's Qt5Gui.dll, or Qt5Widgets.dll. Just look for it. As I already said, I wasn't able to test it on Windows

Comment: I do not understand what is wrong with these files (Qt5Gui.dll and Qt5Widgets.dll)
What should I look for on the Internet?

Comment: What do you mean by "what is wrong with these files"? Do you have them? Have you looked for them *on your computer*? Is the error always the same as your previous comment, using the other names? As I already told you, please don't give informations in bits and pieces, *be more clear*.

Comment: I have these files. It would seem strange to me if these files not existed. Qt5Gui and 
Qt5Widgets are the main files on which the Qt  program rests.Sorry that I misunderstood you.

Comment: I know what those files are for, but since I'm not on windows, I cannot be sure about their names. And I didn't ask you to explain that, so, again, and I hope for the last time, *what is the problem*? Does it still say that the module cannot be found? Or is it another error? You have to answer **all questions** we ask you!!!

Comment: I found what was the problem. the script says (QtGui5.dll) And my file is called (Qt5Gui.dll). I did not notice this because I was looking for QtGui. But now the code has brought out a new problem. `Traceback (most recent call last):File"C:\neon.py",line36,in<module>'qt_blurImage@@YAXPAVQPainter@@AAVQImage@@N_N2H@Z')File"C:\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py",line377,in__getattr__func=self.__getitem__(name)File"C:\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py",line382,in__getitem__func=self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal,self))AttributeError:function'qt_blurImage@@YAXPAVQPainter@@AAVQImage@@N_N2H@Z' not found`

Comment: `?qt_blurImage@@YAXAAVQImage@@N_NH@Z` and `?qt_blurImage@@YAXPAVQPainter@@AAVQImage@@N_N2H@Z` don't work

Comment: @askqest I get the same problem on window10. I will give up then. The code provided is very weird.

Comment: I put that warning for a specific reason: "Consider that this is some sort of a hack, because it uses a private and undocumented function of Qt (which is the same used by QGraphicsBlurEffect) and it's not guaranteed it will work everywhere."

Comment: WoW, I was looking for glowing charts in qtwidgets, (qml has its Glow type: https://www.qt.io/blog/2017/02/07/glowing-qt-charts). This works with charts too, you rock!

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment and editing musicamante's post keep giving me code format error, so I'm posting it here.

Considering QGraphicsEffect is imported from QtWidgets instead of QtGui, so I objdump Qt5Widgets.dll and here's the result:

```
.\objdump.exe -p /Qt5Widgets.dll | findstr "blurImage"
        [5154] ?qt_blurImage@@YAXAEAVQImage@@N_NH@Z
        [5155] ?qt_blurImage@@YAXPEAVQPainter@@AEAVQImage@@N_N2H@Z
```

So on Windows it should be:

```
_qt_blurImage = getattr(ctypes.CDLL('Qt5Widgets.dll'),
        '?qt_blurImage@@YAXPEAVQPainter@@AEAVQImage@@N_N2H@Z')
```

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This option does not cause an error, but now the code again asks `sip` I still didn’t understand why I don’t have it, I installed `PyQT5` several times

Comment: @askqest try `from PyQt5 import sip`

Comment: it works!! How did you manage to mix white and blue?

Comment: @askqest The code is same as musicamante's, but font rendering is different on windows I guess, which result in a different effect. Basically it's just a white label with a blue blur image, the trick is making the blur fits text better.

Comment: I tried to change the color in `setStyleSheet('color:red')` but it didn’t affect anything. I wonder if it is possible to add `NeonEffect` inward. in other words. Somehow invert `setBlurRadius()` to make white color thinner. like [here](https://i.ibb.co/PCWLg1W/wd.gif)

Comment: @askqest probably read about CompositionMode to learn how the effect is blended with the label. As the result, under SourceIn mode text color is always the same as blur color, changing to DestinationIn mode will switch your text color and blur color. but if you mean drawing a white line inside a letter, then I think blur effect is not what you should look for.