# PyQt6 Drop Shadow effect leaves undesired outer border visible against dark background

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt6

I want to use a Drop Shadow effect to smoothen the boundary of a QFrame. Both the frame and the background have darker colors, and this seems to lead to the drop shadow effect leaving a light colored stripe at what I suspect is the bounding rectangle of the effect. In the image below I have zoomed in for it to be easier to see. In my application it looks like a single light colored stripe which outlines a rectangle at the outer boundary of the effect. It is clearly visible if one looks for it. The problem is the outer darker parts that in my opinion should not be there since I would expect them to gradually diminish.

Does anyone know how to get rid of the effect of this "outer rectangle" when using the shadow against a dark background? What I would like is for it to look like in the case with the white background; a dark shadow that gradually disappears as the distance increases from the frame and that does not leave any visible stripes at the boundary of the effect.

I've noticed that the setColor method of the QGraphicsDropShadowEffect has some different parts to it:

```
def setColor(self, Union, QColor=None, Qt_GlobalColor=None, p_int=None, QGradient=None):
```

It's not clear to me what the different parts mean or how I go about and specify them (I do not know how the Union part works). Does anyone know if I can set one of these parts in a way that makes it work against a dark background? Since the shadow effect is flawless against a white background I hope that one can maybe tweak something here to make it work against any background.

[image: Against dark background, white stripes visible]

[image: Against white background, white stripes not visible]

[image: With higher contrast]

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QFrame, QApplication ,QMainWindow,QGraphicsDropShadowEffect
from PyQt6 import QtGui
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication([])

    root = QMainWindow()
    root.setStyleSheet('background-color: #444444')
    root.resize(800,800)

    frame = QFrame(root)
    frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: #111111')
    frame.resize(100,100)
    frame.move(400,400)

    shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect()
    shadow.setBlurRadius(100)
    shadow.setColor(QtGui.QColor('#222222'))
    shadow.setOffset(0, 0)

    frame.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)

    frame.show()
    root.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see what you're referring to, as it's possible that what *I* see is different due to the image compression. Maybe you can post another picture that highlights what you mean (by altering the lightness/contrast) so that we may be able to see it better.

Comment: Yes, it's not super easy to see at first glance but in the top image with the dark background at least I can see a "wave pattern" of brighter and darker parts as the distance increase from the frame. I'm looking at the image uploaded on SO. The last of those "waves" is visible as a rectangle when one runs the code above in full size. I've added a third image with higher contrast, although it alters the perceived effect a bit.

Comment: Mh, it seems a bug, probably caused by the blur filter that is used to draw the shadow. The filter is basically a box blur, which is a linear filter (actually, the Qt one is called "exponential"), which is quite fast, but also not as good as a Gaussian blur would be; the artifacts are probably caused by the way the computation is done: it processes the image in rows of pixel and then processes again the results in columns, and with values too narrow (very similar colors) it can give unexpected results. Unfortunately, that effect doesn't provide the `blurHints` the blur effect has.

Comment: The result is that it always calls the blur filter using the performance mode instead of the quality one, which would use a double pass with a smaller blur radius. Unfortunately there is no direct solution for this. Maybe you could subclass the effect, study the sources and reimplement its [`draw()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsblureffect.html#draw) function manually calling the blur filter (see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60895316), as it's a private method not exposed to the API). I'd suggest to file a report on the [Qt bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io).

Comment: Thanks, OK I will look into the option of subclassing it + file a report.