# PyQt5 QGraphicsDropShadowEffect causes ugly gradient glitch with dark background

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2, visual-glitch

When i use `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` with dark background and darker shadow, it causes gradient glitch. Here the example:

[image: Example]

Is it an IDE glitch or it's a real gradient drawing-issue which will be applied to .exe too?

**UPD**: Even worse with radius 500px as example

[image: Example 2]

Comment: The IDE has absolutely nothing to do with drawing, it is just a development environment, it draws nothing on its own, you could even just use a text editor and you'll obviously have the same result: the library (Qt in this case) used in your program is responsible of drawing, if it does show UI elements. This is probably similar to this [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74578630): it's a bug caused by the drop shadow filter when using very narrow gradients. The only solution is to create a subclass of the effect and manually implement the drawing.

Comment: @musicamante thank you! It looks like solution. Also, i ll attach another link for future searchers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60891262/how-to-make-a-beautiful-neon-effect/60895316#60895316