# How to find "qtblurimage" attribute on PyQt6 dll which is required for neon effect

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt6

I am trying to use neon effect using [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60891262/how-to-make-a-beautiful-neon-effect) but that attribute I.e **?qt_blurImage@@YAXPEAVQPainter@@AEAVQImage@@N_N2H@Z** in **Qt6Widgets.dll**
How to know what has been introduced in this place in PyQt6 or it has been removed!!.

Comment: Add a comment there, don't create a question for this.

Comment: This is not a duplicate . That answer was for pyqt5 but I can't use this in pyqt6. It must be changed.And there was a method which uses "objdump" to get the name. But for some reason It is not working for me.

Comment: That's not that relevant, the question and its answer is fundamentally the same, just ensure that you're using the correct DLL name and path, as the attribute name for the function is still the same even in Qt6.

Comment: I am providing correct path still it saying attribute error. Can you please confirm?

Comment: If it doesn't work, we need more details about *what* doesn't work. Is your issue with the CDLL function? If that's so, the problem has nothing to do with PyQt, but with the Qt library. In any case, you should provide the full traceback. It is possible that you're using a different build/version (I checked it with a downloaded Qt6Widgets.dll and `objdump` returns the same string), so I suggest you to check it on your own. If you don't have the GNU binutils (which includes objdump), use similar tools (AFAIK, dumpbin might be a valid alternative).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem lies in **PyQt6** they have just changed the name of that attribute slightly.
In **PyQt5** --

```
?qt_blurImage@@YAXPAVQPainter@@AAVQImage@@N_N2H@Z
```

But in **PyQt6** it has been changed to

```
?qt_blurImage@@YAXPEAVQPainter@@AEAVQImage@@N_N2H@Z
```

Now we can use this in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60891262/how-to-make-a-beautiful-neon-effect)

To detect in attribute name in future version, **objdump** could be a choice but for my case **dumpbin** helped me.

Here is the command in Powershell

```
PS C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\Hostx64\x64> .\dumpbin.exe /EXPORTS "C:\Users\Prem\Desktop\Qt6Widgets.dll" |findstr ?qt_blurImage
```

Output will be like

```
4873 1308 000E4A20 ?qt_blurImage@@YAXAEAVQImage@@N_NH@Z
4874 1309 000E4AA0 ?qt_blurImage@@YAXPEAVQPainter@@AEAVQImage@@N_N2H@Z
```

Comment: As said, the difference is in Qt, **NOT** PyQt. And, still, you should have mentioned that in a comment to the original answer (or eventually a further answer to that post).